# Auto-update of features?

Tags: features

On a production site, I don't want admins to be able to perform many tasks at all, to limit the risks the site is exposed to, so modules like "Views UI" will be turned off.

However, I still want a number of administrators to have access to Views and similar functionality, so they can perform changes without a developers help.

Thus I would like to see the ability to have *some* features "auto-export" themselves, a script that commits them to the VCS, and then deploys to a stage-server where they can be tested and approved.

Is there any public work at all on this type of functionality, or would I need to start from scratch? Is the idea entirely in-sane, and if so, what other options should I pursue?

Comment: I don't know how big is the site, but in a perfect world you should have 3 copies of your site. One the DEV copy where developers can add to the site, two the STAGE copy where the admins can test the new features and three the PRODUCTION or LIVE copy that your users see and use. The guys from Pantheon have it automated and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

My own suggestion is a cron job that runs

```
@drush fu [feature 1] [feature 2]
git commit -m "Auto exported features" features-dir/
git push
```

and while that could certainly work, I'm also fairly certain all kinds of problems will be discovered along the way, meaning this script will need to evolve substantially over time.

Leaving question open at least until someone with actual experience (maybe myself) leaves an answer.